Closure of a finite projective plane under union
Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the family of sets formed by the sets of points incident to each line of a finite projective plane with its order $n$ a prime power and built with vector space construction. For example for the Fano plane $\mathcal{G} = \{\{0,1,2\},\{0,3,4\},
\{0, 5, 6\},
\{1, 3, 5\},
\{2, 4, 5\},
\{2, 3, 6\},
\{1, 4, 6\}\}$. The number of elements of $\mathcal{G}$ is the number of points of the plane: $n^2+n+1$.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the closure of $\mathcal{G}$ under set union.
Can we use some property of the structure of the plane to prove that the average size of the sets in $\mathcal{F}$ is at least $(n^2+n+1)/2$?
I have just checked numerically the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$, above that it seems computationally infeasible.
EDIT 2024-09-04
As a first step, I managed to prove that every possible set with size in $[n^2+1, n^2+n+1]$ must belong to $\mathcal{F}$. Such a set has $m$ elements missing $x_1, \ldots , x_m$, with $0 \le m \le n$. To build that set we can take the union of all sets in $\mathcal{G}$ excluding at most $m(n+1) \le n^2+n$ sets, i.e. excluding all sets whose intersection is some $\{x_i\}$. In this way all other $n^2+n+1-m$ elements will belong to the set: suppose that this is not true, then there is an element $y \not= x_j, j=1,\ldots,m$, such that the $n+1$ sets in $\mathcal{G}$ that give $\{y\}$ as intersection are within those excluded from the union; but $m \le n$, therefore $(n+1)/m \gt 1$ and there are at least $2$ sets excluded from the union that give both some $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y\}$ as intersection, absurd.
